# Series connected MOSFETs effect on the channel length

Tags: mosfet, nmos

I understand that connecting two NMOS in series for example increases the transistor channel length in concept. But consider having two series connected NMOS with the same channel length "L", can we say that this configuration is equivalent, in power consumption and resistance, to a single NMOS transistor with channel length of "2L"? 
And how we can calculate the equivalent channel length of N connected NMOS with the same channel length of "L", is there like a formula or equation to get this?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Depends on the construction of the fet and what other design parameters you have.

Comment: I'm just assuming that every other parameter is the same. Same width, and everything. Would both configurations be equivalent to each other in power consumption? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For two NMOS transistors in series with the gates tied together one transistor is in saturation the other one in the linear region.

Based on the simple square law model it can be derived that the equivalent dimensions are
$$
\left(\frac{W}{L}\right)_{eq} = \frac{\left(\frac{W}{L}\right)_{1}\left(\frac{W}{L}\right)_{2}}{\left(\frac{W}{L}\right)_{1}+\left(\frac{W}{L}\right)_{2}}
$$

Applying this equation repeatedly it can be used for more than two transistors.

For two transistors of length L the equivalent length turns out to be 2L if the widths stay the same.

Comment: Thank you so much for your helpful answer.
In that case, I don't think both configurations would consume the same power right? I think the capacitance at the common node between the two series connected NMOS would contribute in the power or something. I'm not so sure. What do you think when it comes to power consumption?

Comment: The configurations are equivalent. The total power consumption is therefore equal.

Comment: @Mario Just wondering, how did you manage to derive that equivalent dimensions equation

Comment: The square law dosen't apply to the device in linear/triode, hence, this doesn't appear correct to me.

Answer (score 0):

No.

While calculating the combined effect of NMOS transistors in series, their source/drain capacitances need to be taken into consideration.

For instance, two NMOS in series connected to a capacitive load C_load

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fNt1RQ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

will actually behave like this when the gates are turned on:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fdv9GF.png)</sup>

and not like this (a longer NMOS):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fxXpyJ.png)</sup>

(In the diagrams, R1 and R2 are the equivalent channel resistances of the two transistors, CD2 is the drain capacitance of the bottom transistor and CS1 is the source capacitance of the upper transistor)

The presence of an effective capacitance of CD2+CS1 between the two channels changes the way the transistors charge or discharge the load, which in turn affects the circuit's timing as well as power consumption.

Comment: Thank you very much for your elaboration. I thought that too that the two configurations are going to be different when it comes to power consumption. So, I think if we are talking about leakage or standby power, that the configuration with two transistors in series would consume larger power than the equivalent transistor with double the channel length right? also the dynamic power should be larger?

Comment: Hmm, the leakage power should more or less be the same for both; but dynamic power should be larger for two transistors in series than a single longer one (since it has to charge/discharge two capacitors instead of one in the same clock window).